# How do I update a store that is in local storage with SvelteKit?

Tags: sveltekit

I am trying to update a store that is in local storage when I fetch data from Supabase.
The store always appears blank in the browser inspector even after using set() or update() or just by doing `store.value = anotherValue`. I have looked over the docs for this and looked through different tutorials but nothing has this specific use case.

If I do `let firmNameVar = firmStore.firmName` then I can get the value but I still don't see it in the browser inspector in local storage.

**The Store Code:**

```js
import { writable } from "svelte/store";
import { browser } from "$app/environment";

export const storedFirm = JSON.parse(browser && localStorage.getItem("firmStore")) || {
    firmID: '',
    firmName: '',
    firmAddress: '',
    firmPhoneNumber: '',
    firmWebsite: '',
    firmType: '',
    firmMembers: [''],
    firmProjects: [''],
    firmRoles: [''],
    firmPermissionsID: '',
    firmComplete: Boolean,
    completeYourProfile: Boolean,
    buildYourTeam: Boolean,
    definePermissions: Boolean,
    aboutYourWork: Boolean,
    errorConnectingToSupabase: Boolean
    };

export const firmStore = writable(browser && storedFirm);
firmStore.subscribe(
(val) => browser && (localStorage.firmStore = JSON.stringify(val))
    );
```

**Code to Update the Store:**

```js
import { firmStore } from "/src/stores/firmStore";
///CONNECTING TO DATABASE
async function queryFirmDatabase(){
    const { data: firm, error } = await supabaseClient
          .from('firms')
          .select('id, firm_name,firm_address, firm_phone, firm_website, firm_projects, firm_complete, complete_your_profile, build_your_team, define_permissions, about_work')
          .eq('id', clientUser.orgID)
          if (firm){

///CONNECTED TO DATABASE AND TRYING TO ASSIGN VALUE TO STORE OBJECT

          const [fetchedUser] = firm;
          try {
            firmStore.firmName.set(fetchedUser.firm_name);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Doesn't work")
            }
        } else {
          console.log("THERE WAS AN ERROR FETCHING FROM FIRM DATABASE")
          console.log(error)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simply not valid:

```js
localStorage.firmStore = JSON.stringify(val)
```

You need to use `localStorage.setItem(key, value)`.

Comment: Cannot find name "key"

Comment: Please think before simply copying something. I just gave the signature with names of the arguments...

Comment: Doesn't work for the other properties of the object either...

Comment: What do you mean by "other properties"? You want to store the whole object, right? It's just `setItem("firmStore", JSON.stringify(val))`.